# How regular columns become managed properties?

Tags: 2013, search-results, display-template

I Customize Display Template for Content By Search result Web Part. Then, Add a reference to your custom managed property in the display template to the ManagedPropertyMapping attribute.

But, when I Create a placeholder in the body of the Item display template for the managed property using syntax like:

```
ctx.CurrentItem.MyManagedProperty
```

ctx command return null, because regular columns will not automatically become managed properties when they are crawled.

How **regular columns** (not Site columns) become managed properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These columns need to be mapped from crawled properties (the on that the search have found) to the managed properties. This mapping won't me made automatically.

How this mapping can be done and what the difference between mapped and crawled properties is can be found here:

[The search schema in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219669(v=office.15).aspx)

[Manage search schema in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667(v=office.15).aspx)

You will find a complete list of managed and crawled properties that have been preconfigured:
[Crawled and managed properties in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630(v=office.15).aspx)